# Как сделать бота на Python который будет подбирать рандомные 12 символов состоящих из букв и цифр и запоминать их чтобы не повторять в будущем

Tags: python, бот, искусственный-интеллект, случайные-числа

Я пытаюсь написать бота на Python который будет вводить рандомные 12 символов, состоящих из букв и цифр, сохранять каждые 12 символов и сделать так чтобы не повторять их в будущем.

Вот код который я написал на данный момент:

```
import pyautogui as root
from random import randint
from time import sleep
*while 1 == 1: 
    print( root.position() )
    root.moveTo( 900, 550, 0.5 )
    root.click()
    sleep( 0.1 )
    symbols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Q', 'W', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', 'S', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X', 'V', 'N', 'M', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
    lenn = 12
    result = ' '
    for i in range(lenn):
        n = randint(0, len(symbols) - 1)
        element = str(symbols[n])
        result += element
    root.typewrite( result )*
    root.moveTo( 1700, 970, 0.5 )
    root.click()
    root.moveTo( 964, 858, 0.5 )
    root.click()
```

Нужно переделать его так как я указал в самом верху.

Буду очень благодарен если кто-то поможет решить мою проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте множество, чтобы хранить список уникальных результатов и быстро проверять, встречался ли уже сгенерированный результат ранее:

```
result_set = set() # инициализация множества

while 1 == 1:

    # ...

    symbols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Q', 'W', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', 'S', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X', 'V', 'N', 'M', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
    lenn = 12
    result = ' '
    while True: # цикл пока не найдём новую последовательность
        for i in range(lenn):
            n = randint(0, len(symbols) - 1)
            element = str(symbols[n])
            result += element
        if result not in result_set: # проверка, нет ли уже такой последовательности
            result_set.add(result) # добавляем найденную последовательность
            break # прерываем цикл
```